# neo4j: change of execution plan in dependence on return limit

Tags: neo4j, query-optimization, database-performance, sql-execution-plan

In our neo4j version 5.5 database, we have data `(c1:Company)-[:ADDRESS_MATCH]-(c2:company)` as well as `(t:CompanyNameToken)-[:CONTAINS_TOKEN]-(c:Company)`. Our goal is to find companies with address match and a common token. The execution plan changes unexpectedly, as follows. Matching only the addresses is quick and results in the following execution plan, with 1645 DB hits in 14ms.

```
PROFILE MATCH (c1:Company)-[:ADDRESS_MATCH]->(c2:Company)
RETURN c1, c2 LIMIT 100
```

[image]

The execution plan stays the same when increasing the limit of 100 or removing the limit. Now adding the token match as a condition, for `LIMIT 100` the execution plan still has only one branch, with 250.000 DB hits in 58ms.

```
PROFILE MATCH (c1:Company)-[:ADDRESS_MATCH]->(c2:Company),
(c1)<-[r1:CONTAINS_TOKEN]-(t:CompanyNameToken)-[r2:CONTAINS_TOKEN]->(c2)
RETURN c1, c2 LIMIT 100
```

[image]

However, when executing the same query with `LIMIT 300` instead of `LIMIT 100`, the execution plan involves multiple branches (cartesian product on `c1`, `c2`) and suddenly has 38 Million DB hits in much longer 12000ms. (The transition is somewhere between 200 and 300).

```
PROFILE MATCH (c1:Company)-[:ADDRESS_MATCH]->(c2:Company),
(c1)<-[r1:CONTAINS_TOKEN]-(t:CompanyNameToken)-[r2:CONTAINS_TOKEN]->(c2)
return c1, c2 limit 300
```

[image]

A reformulation of the above query with the `exists` keyword does not show this behavior. The execution plan stays the same, independent of the limit, or even without the limit. For `LIMIT 300`, it has 600.000 DB hits in only 190ms.

```
PROFILE MATCH (c1:Company)-[:ADDRESS_MATCH]->(c2:Company)
WHERE EXISTS {(c1)<-[r1:CONTAINS_TOKEN]-(t:CompanyNameToken)-[r2:CONTAINS_TOKEN]->(c2)}
return c1, c2 limit 300
```

[image]

Three questions:

- What is the reason for this behavior?
- The execution plan for `LIMIT 100` is the way it should be, avoiding an unnecessary cartesian product. The plan for `LIMIT 300` is hopelessly naive. Is there a way to force neo4j to the first execution plan, maybe with some planner hints?
- Why is the exection plan different when using the variant involving `EXISTS`?

I tried various planner hints and combinations with no success. Confusingly, some days before, this behavior did not show up, with almost the same data. I read that execution plans depend on the DB statistics. However, commands like `CALL db.clearQueryCaches()` or `CALL db.prepareForReplanning()` also did not change the behavior.

Comment: I would report this directly to Neo4j repository: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the [EXISTS](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/predicate/#functions-exists) function, it will immediately return `true` as soon as it finds a single match. So it can be *much faster and less memory-intensive* than looking for and keeping in memory all matches.

Since your use case doesn't need to use **all** the `CompanyNameToken` subpaths, it makes sense to just use the `EXISTS` version of your query.